# Undefined reference to ‘cudaGetDeviceCount’ Undefined reference to ‘cudaGetDeviceProperties’

Tags: makefile, cuda, nvidia

checkGPU.cpp :

```
#include<iostream>
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    cudaDeviceProp prop;

    int count;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&count);
   // cudaGetDeviceCount(&count);//获取设备数
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop,i);//将第i个GPU数据放到prop中
        std::cout<<"显卡名称："<<prop.name<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"显存大小："<<prop.totalGlobalMem/1024/1024<<" MB"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"一个block的共享内存大小："<<prop.sharedMemPerBlock/1024<<" KB"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"block最大线程数："<<prop.maxThreadsPerBlock<<std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

makefile is:

```
.PHONY: clean, all
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -O3 

INCLUDE=-I./ \
        -I/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include

LIBS =-L/usr/lib -lcuda


OBJS= checkGPU.o
all:
    make checkGPU
checkGPU: checkGPU.o
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 checkGPU.o -o checkGPU $(LIBS) $(OBJS)
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 $(INCLUDE) -fPIC -c $< -o $@
clean:
    -rm *.o
    -rm checkGPU
```

lastly, make it, error is:

```
Undefined reference to ‘cudaGetDeviceCount’ Undefined reference to ‘cudaGetDeviceProperties’
```

Answer (score 3):

`cudaGetDeviceCount()` and `cudaGetDeviceProperties()` are part of the [CUDA Runtime API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html). To use these, you have to link libcudart. libcuda is the [CUDA Driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html), which is basically an entirely different way of using CUDA. While [it is possible to mix](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#interoperability-between-runtime-and-driver-apis) both APIs, that is something one better only does when absolutely necessary. In your case, it would seem that you simply intended to just use the CUDA Runtime API. In this case, just link `-lcudart` instead of `-lcuda`.

Apart from that, note that `system("pause");` will most likely not do much for you as you appear to be using Linux…

Answer (score 0):

In addition to needing to use `-lcudart` as outlined in the other answer,  libraries need appear after the objects, so the Makefile needs to use the following to do the linking

```
checkGPU: checkGPU.o
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 -o checkGPU $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```